# XAMPP me muestra Notice: Undefined index: y en el hosting funciona perfecto :S HELP PHP 5.6

Tags: php, web, xampp, php5, session

Tengo el siguiente código en mi `index.php`

```
include_once 'acceso/conection.php';
session_name('2131321312');
session_start();
if (!($_SESSION['id_sucursal']) and ($_SESSION['login'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ' . $tienda);
}
```

Donde valido que si no existe `session`, destruya la sesión y redireccione a la URL almacenada en `$tienda`, ahora bien, más abajo en la misma pagina tengo validaciones que muestran la información dependiente de si existe la sesión o no como lo muestro a continuación:

```
if ($_SESSION['id_sucursal']) {
    $maximo = $bd->getProductosSucursalesMax($_SESSION['id_sucursal']);
} else {
    $maximo = $bd->getProductosSucursalesMax2();
}
```

En el hosting me funciona perfecto, pero estoy replicando el ambiente de desarrollo con **XAMPP** y cuando cargo la página me muestra el mensaje `Notice: Undefined index: id_sucursal` en todas las líneas donde imprimo o valido el `$_SESSION['id_sucursal']` directamente.

¿Qué tiene de diferente mi XAMPP que me muestra dicha advertencia?

Comment: En qué carpeta estás guardando los archivos en XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos directivas principales en PHP que te permiten reportar y/o mostrar errores:

- `error_reporting` te permite configurar qué errores serán reportados.
- `display_errors` te permite mostrar los errores en pantalla.

Es probable que en la configuración de directivas de tu hosting tenga una configuración diferente a la que tienes en tu equipo local.

Por ejemplo, en entornos de producción se sugiere poner la directiva `display_errors` en `0` (para no mostrar ningún error al usuario final), y `error_reporting` en `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED` (sólo reportar errores críticos del sistema, dejar de lado aquellos que no afectan su funcionamiento). En cambio en un entorno de desarrollo se suele utilizar `display_errors` en `1` y `error_reporting` en `E_ALL`.

Estas configuraciones pueden ser cambiadas en tu `php.ini` (windows) o `php/conf.d` (linux), si no tienes acceso a la configuración de tu hosting puedes probar de cambiarlos en tiempo de ejecución con los métodos:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php

Ya de última, para corregir el NOTICE que te salió puedes aplicar la solución que te dio @Andrés Macías

Comment: gracias con esto pude avanzar, si lo conocía pero no me imagine que era eso, pensé que era relacionado con las versiones u otra cosa. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Has el check con isset.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id_sucursal'] && isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ' . $tienda);
}
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias ...